# CoordinatorLayout layout_anchor does not work with Floating action botton

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having problems with [this FAB from GitHub](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) to anchor properly with my custom toolbar which I named in the xml file viewA:[layout with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDKGD.png)
I tried using coordinator_layout but I can't seem to make it work.

I would like it to have anchor it to my *viewA* on the right bottom side.

**My current layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_subject"
    tools:context="com.example.coquenim.gradebook.Activities.SubjectActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Your grade"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="70dp"
                android:paddingEnd="70dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Goal"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerPadding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="18.75"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/subjectAveragee"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="20.00"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/subject_target_grade"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/currentSubjectName"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorBlack"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:childDivider="#00000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/currentSubjectName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
        fab:menu_openDirection="down">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_box_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_showAnimation="@anim/show_from_bottom"
            fab:fab_hideAnimation="@anim/hide_to_bottom"/>

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Looking at the github for the library, it does not look like it supports `layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` attributes.

Comment: @AlexTownsend but you can see it in their example [link] (https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/raw/master/screenshots/menu_down_opened.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this layout](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/floating_menus_activity.xml) from the library's github. They're achieving what looks like an anchor by having a fixed height header and using padding/margins to align the FABs along the bottom of the header `TextView`, making it look like it is achieving the `CoordinatorLayout`'s `layout_anchor`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, one beginner question having fixed height header and using padding to align the FABs would that work for all screen sizes?

Comment: As long as you're defining the margin/padding in `dp` you should be good to go, but it's always a good idea to test out a few different screen densities whether through the emulator or different devices.